# How to disable hotkeys / shortcuts on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an external keyboard connected to a tablet which runs an app. I would like to disable any inputs other than letters, space and some special marks. The keyboard has little knobs which control the volume which I would also like to disable. Or things like ALT-F4 which seems to activate some internet mode, open the browser, etc.

I tried disabling hotkeys in Android but could not find out where.

I tried filtering out all unwanted inputs in the app itself with the "onKeyUp" function but not all keys seem to register (e.g. multimedia keys)

Is this something that has to be configured in Android? Or coded in Kotlin?

Cheerio!